# Stream network distance between specific paired points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, network-analyst

I have a stream network dataset and am attempting to do a distance analysis between paired points located in two different layers. Ex. I have 500 points in layer A with given coordinates, and then 500 points with different coordinates in layer B. I plan to base the distance-pairing on a shared ID. Having looked at other questions related to this, I have often seen the OD Cost Matrix suggested as a solution, or tools that give linear distance. I don't think the OD Cost Matrix will work for me- I want the stream network distance between the points that share an ID, not the distance between Point A and all other points.

Comment: Insert additional nodes at intersections with points. Use any shortest path algorithm to find relative distances. Network x package is a way to go

Comment: @PolGeo this is not exact duplicate because from A to B it could be very well going downstream to relevant junction and continue upstream to B. This is what boats do. Referred answer deals with directional graph

Answer (score 0):

I actually just did something like this not too long ago.  Have a look at [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193788/finding-the-distance-between-points-in-two-different-layers-along-a-route-in-arc/193806#193806) to [Finding distance between points in two different layers along route in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/193788/115).  I used Python to find the distance along a line between two points that intersect each line.